# How to restart my node js app when the CPU usage reach 100% on Amazon EC2 and the server stops

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, forever

Currently i am using [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) to handle crashes,etc on EC2 but i want some way to manage restarting the app when the CPU usage on the server reaches 100%.

The way it works now is that when the CPU usage reach 100% the app stops running and if i didn't notice the alarms sent by amazon on my mail the app remains down until i restart ***manually*** it again using [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever).

What i want is a way for when the cpu usage reach 90% or higher it restarts the app, should i use another module other than forever and if so any suggestions ?

Comment: I sure hope you're also working on the root cause for 100% CPU usage because that seems like the bigger issue here.  If you just restart a process that will go right back to 100% CPU usage as soon as it gets started again, that won't do you any good.

Comment: Yeah, you are right but the problem is that it is not a regular issue, for now it's just spikes happening during weird times like every 3 or 4 days.

Answer (score 1):

I recommand you to reduce your CPU usage BUT, I use a similar tricks but to restart when memory usage is to high (due to very small memory leak)

You need module "usage"

```
var usage       = require('usage');
```

then:

```
CHECK_CPU_USAGE_INTERVAL    = 1000*60; // every minute
HIGH_CPU_USAGE_LIMIT        = 90; // percentage

autoRestart = setInterval(function()
{
    usage.lookup(process.pid, function(err, result) 
    {
        if(!err)
        {
            if(result.cpu > HIGH_CPU_USAGE_LIMIT)
            {
                // log
                console.log('restart due to high cpu usage');

                // restart because forever will respawn your process
                process.exit();
            }
        }
    });
}, CHECK_CPU_USAGE_INTERVAL);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work because the application seems to stop functioning when it reaches 100% cpu.

Comment: So you have to find what's the source of the high cpu consumption and fix it :)

Comment: Do you have any ideas to help with that ? :) as currently i have no clue whats the cause of the problem.

Comment: Depends on so many facts, try to find possible infinite loop or code that do a heavy process etc.

Comment: @KarimTarek if this doesn't work, it may be that it's going from 90% to 100% in less than a minute (the check period) - you could reduce the check perioud to e.g 5 secs, and have a better chance of catching and restarting.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Forever:
https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever

You can use it for the exact situation described. Thought i'd try to figure out why you're hitting max CPU.

Comment: Indeed i already use forever but forever just dont restart the application when the server reaches max CPU (100%) it just shows like the process is there in forever list running but the app is not. And every time that happens i have to use forever restart manually.